# How can I turn right click off and on using functions in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, right-click

I have disabled right click in my application using the following:

```
  <body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

I have a textarea element which has spellcheck enabled. I want to be able to right-click in this field (for spellcheck) but I want right-click to be disabled everywhere else in the app.

I have done the following:

```
  <textarea onfocus="rightclickon()" onblur="rightclickoff()" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
```

These are the functions:

```
function rightclickon() {
$('body').prop('oncontextmenu', 'null');
}//end rightclickon
function rightclickoff() {
$('body').prop('oncontextmenu', 'return false');
}//end rightclickoff
```

My logic behind the above is that whenever the user enters the textarea, right-click would be enabled but when they leave the field, it would be disabled again. This does not work how I expected.

The first part works (right-click is enabled when the ueser enters the field). However, when the field is left, right-click does not get disabled again. It just remains on.

Is their an easier way to achieve what I want?

Comment: why would you disable right click?

Comment: To make the HTML app feel more like an "app" and less like a website.

Comment: Disabling the browser context menu is annoying to users. There's rarely a good reason to do it, and wanting to get a certain "feel" is not a good reason. And tech-savvy users can get around it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply inspect the origin of the event and decide what to do accordingly

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('textarea')) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}, false)
```

```html
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<ul>
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
</ul>

<textarea>Just try right-clicking in here</textarea>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/matches for details about `Element.matches`

Comment: interestingly if you hold down shift in Firefox it does show the context menu while right clicking

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @MatthewLock yes, there's usually plenty of ways around sites that attempt to block right-clicking

Comment: This should never be implemented... Some user groups will hate you for it. Anyway +1

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt agreed. I'd like to think of this answer as more of a guide to deterministic event handling